# system center configuration manager

Tags: sccm, system-center

I have a colleague that is looking for help with the following situation. If anyone can be of assistance, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

From his email:

A couple of months ago, the admin spent quite a bit of time installing SCCM as a pilot.  (We have no experience with System Center here prior to this.)  Because it was a pilot and on a test box, he installed it using our domain's Administrator account, which still was called "Administrator", and had not added any other admins.  About a week ago, our admins completed a project to change the name of Administrator domain-wide to something else to improve our domain security.  Unfortunately, because this system is in test, it was missed during the systems review, and we can no longer administer SCCM.

The best possible scenario would be to find a way to get System Center to recognize the new name of Administrator so we can administer SCCM.  The only solution we've found on the Internet is to completely reinstall it, which our admin is reluctant to do because of the time invested in installing and configuring it - he was getting close to rolling it out companywide.  I know it's a long shot, but I thought you might know of something anecdotal that might be able to help us, or that you might know of someone else you could refer me to.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you change the Administrator back to the original name for about 15 mins? Have you already tried this?

Having installed SCOM/Reporting Services/Sharepoint I can feel your co-workers pain.

*Edit:*

Duh. Hold on. Tell your coworker to:

1. Shutdown the SCCM service
2. Backup the SCCM database
3. Reinstall SCCM on a new system (with it's own user account)
4. Point the new SCCM system at the OLD database.
5. Cross your fingers.

This might work.

Comment: A note to everyone: Do not ever use the Domain Admin (or Eterprise Admin) account to run a service. Especially if it's a a test.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way to tell SCCM about the new administrator account. Even if you could, you really don't want to be using a domain admin account for this service. It's a pain, but your best action would be to wipe and reinstall. If it's a test box, this shouldn't be a big deal. Doubly so if it's an image.